# Why different test order will get different result?

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking

I changed the test order and get different result. I tried disable opcode cache, added unset, but still get different result. Why ?

http://snipplr.com/view/759/

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$myArray = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i )
{
   $myArray[] = $i;
   $myArray[] = 'test a string';
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
printf("Took %f seconds for array[]\n", $time_end - $time_start);

$time_start = microtime(true);

$myArray = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i )
{
   array_push($myArray, $i);
   array_push($myArray, 'test a string');
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
printf("Took %f seconds for array_push\n", $time_end - $time_start);
```

Took 0.145872 seconds for array[] Took 0.154502 seconds for array_push

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$myArray = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i )
{
   array_push($myArray, $i);
   array_push($myArray, 'test a string');
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
printf("Took %f seconds for array_push\n", $time_end - $time_start);

$time_start = microtime(true);

$myArray = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i )
{
   $myArray[] = $i;
   $myArray[] = 'test a string';
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
printf("Took %f seconds for array[]\n", $time_end - $time_start);
```

Took 0.197076 seconds for array_push Took 0.122565 seconds for array[]

Increase test number to 500000:

Took 0.779719 seconds for array[] Took 0.757806 seconds for array_push

Took 1.008018 seconds for array_push Took 0.494230 seconds for array[]

See if I change test order. it's 2X speed difference.

Comment: Try with array[] and array[] and second test with array_push x2 to remove 'array_push vs. []' aspect, and we will se what will happen

Answer (score 2):

my thought is about memory usage: i added echo of difference of `memory_get_usage()` (just like the time) and saw this:

```
Took 0.108744 seconds for array_push
memory: 32497848
Took 0.151069 seconds for array_push
memory: 320
```

and

```
Took 0.061715 seconds for array[]
memory: 32499584
Took 0.058831 seconds for array[]
memory: -40
```

so: `array_push()` seems not to be cleaning memory allocated for the script, and `array[]` seems to do so. php needs some time to allocate new memory (i guess), so `array[]` after `array_push()` doesn't need to spend time on it, but `array_push()` after `array[]` does.

or, maybe it's a delirium

ps: so, to increase performance one has to call a function which consumes much memory and doesn't clean up at the beginning of the script?! %|